# Extract columns from file

Tags: perl

I would like to extract some columns from a file in Perl. Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'file.txt';

open( my $fh, "<" ,$file) or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
     if (/a/../z/) {
       next if /a/ || /z/;
       print +(split) [5,6,7], "\n";
      }
}
```

Output of this code:

```
1ALACA

1ALACB

2THRH

2THRCA
```

I would like the output instead to read (just adding some more spaces, making it easier to read):

```
1   ALA  CA

1   ALA  CB

2   THR   H

2   THR  CA
```

Comment: [`perldoc -f join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#join-EXPR%2cLIST)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use spaces to join the columns?

```
print join("  ", +(split)[5,6,7]), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change the Output Field Separator before the loop:

```
$, = ' ';
```

Or more explicitly:

```
use English qw<$OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR>;

local $OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR = ' ';
```